# Change/delete matching brackets at the same time

Tags: cursor-motions, replace

Sometimes I write something in brackets and then realize I've typed the wrong kind. For instance, in LaTeX:

```
\command(arguments)
```

Which should be:

```
\command{arguments}
```

I can jump between the two parentheses/braces using `%`, but since `%` doesn't work after the opening delimiter has been changed, in order to change both of the braces I have to do something like:

```
%r{f)r}
```

This doesn't seem like a big deal, but I find that switching from brace to parenthesis in the middle of the command sequence creates a surprising amount of cognitive dissonance, and this task often takes much longer than it feels like it ought to. Is there a plugin or simple hack that would provide an easier way? I would like it to be able to handle multiple pairs on the same line, so a simple substitution won't work, and I'd rather not define separate mappings for every pair of delimiters I'd like to convert between. (Just off the top of my head, `'`, `"`, `()`, `{}`, and `[]` are all in the list I need to convert between, and I'd probably sooner or later find a use for `<>` as well.)

A related problem is entirely removing a pair of brackets -- say I'm writing prose and have a sentence in parentheses and then decide it shouldn't be in them anymore. I can use `da(` to get rid of the whole clause, or `di(` to get rid of the content, but I want to get rid of the parentheses. The resulting command `%xf)x` is much less annoying, but there's still some room for improvement.

Comment: You will love [Surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround).

Comment: @romainl shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: @romainl That's hilarious – I *have* Surround, but I never knew it could change or delete existing delimiters! I guess I should read the documentation every now and then to see what I'm forgetting.

Comment: (And if you put that as an answer with a brief summary of the commands I'll be happy to accept it.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) does what you want and *more*:

```
ds(    delete first surrounding pair of parentheses
2ds(   delete second surrounding pair of parentheses
cs[{   change surrounding pair of square brackets into a pair of braces
```

See `:help surround`.