# How to replace [ with ( in vim

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, filetype-markdown

I have this markdown line,

`![Home][screenshots/home.png]`

I want to replace it with,

`![Home](screenshots/home.png)`

So, I tried this,

`:%s/[s/(s/g`

Vim(version 81) says `pattern not found.`

Comment: Pro tip: use [vim-sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich) or [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround), they both work great to change a pair of character quickly. No need to do it manually.

Comment: Possible dupes: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21682/10604, https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7264/10604

Comment: The error you're getting ("pattern not found") is due to `[` starting a character class in a regex (see [`:help /[]`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5B%5D). You need to escape it with a backslash. This should work: `:%s/\[s/(s/g`. But much better is to use something like [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround), which gives you commands to switch the `[]` pair with a `()` pair in a single command (`cs])` anywhere inside that block.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the opening square bracket:

`:%s/\[s/(s/g`

For the whole replace, you can use:

`:%s/]\[\(.)]/](\1)`

Comment: Yes worked!! I did it two times for opening and closing brackets. `:%s/\[s/(s/g` and `:%s/\g]/g)/g`